# Multiplying matrices with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices with different dimensions that I would like to multiply using einsum numpy:
C(24, 79) and  D(1, 1, 24, 1). I want to obtain the matrix with the dimension (1, 1, 79, 1).

I have tried to multiply them in two ways:

```
tmp = np.einsum('px, klpj ->klxj', C, D)

tmp = np.einsum('xp, klpj ->klxj', C, D)
```

and I'm obtaining different results. Why? What is the correct way of multiplying these matrices?

Comment: The first one is correct. I cannot reproduce the second one; it throws an error (as it should).

Comment: Curious if the posted solution work for/helped you?

Comment: Honestly, I still struggle with understanding why the first answer is correct. Will it be the same if the matrix D has a (1,1,79,1) dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Owing to the singleton dimensions that don't really result in `sum-reduction`, we can introduce matrix-multiplication with [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) or [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to have two more approaches to solve it -

```
np.tensordot(C,D,axes=([0],[2])).swapaxes(0,2)

D.ravel().dot(C).reshape(1,1,C.shape[1],1)
```

Verify results -

```
In [26]: tmp = np.einsum('px, klpj ->klxj', C, D)

In [27]: out = np.tensordot(C,D,axes=([0],[2])).swapaxes(0,2) 

In [28]: np.allclose(out, tmp)
Out[28]: True

In [29]: out = D.ravel().dot(C).reshape(1,1,C.shape[1],1)

In [30]: np.allclose(out, tmp)
Out[30]: True
```

Runtime test -

```
In [31]: %timeit np.einsum('px, klpj ->klxj', C, D)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.84 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit np.tensordot(C,D,axes=([0],[2])).swapaxes(0,2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit D.ravel().dot(C).reshape(1,1,C.shape[1],1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.29 µs per loop
```

With bigger datasets, you would see noticeable benefits with matrix-multiplication -

```
In [36]: C = np.random.rand(240,790)
    ...: D = np.random.rand(1,1,240,1)
    ...: 

In [37]: %timeit np.einsum('px, klpj ->klxj', C, D)
    ...: %timeit np.tensordot(C,D,axes=([0],[2])).swapaxes(0,2)
    ...: %timeit D.ravel().dot(C).reshape(1,1,C.shape[1],1)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 182 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.9 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.5 µs per loop
```